# OneNote API - 401 Error

Tags: onenote-api

I am following the blog (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/onenotedev/archive/2015/06/11/and-sharepoint-makes-three.aspx) to access one note files stored in Office 365 sharepoint tenant. I registered my app and was able to acquire token but when When I use the accessToken access the following URL

www.onenote.com/.../FromUrl(url='https://*****.sharepoint.com/sites/")

I am always getting a 401. Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: 401 indicates an Authentication failure. Does the token you acquired work for any of the API routes? What scope did you use when acquiring the token?

Comment: Another thing to check: Does the user you used to get the access token have access to that site?

Comment: The registered app (Web Application/Web API app) has access to OneNote application and delegated permissions "View OneNote notebooks". It also has access to Office 365 Sharepoint Online and Delegated permissions to "Read items in site collections". I have a console app that is acquiring token on behalf of this registered app and using that token to call https://www.onenote.com/.../FromUrl(url='https://*****.sharepoint.com/sites/").

Comment: I tried to directly fire a get to https://www.onenote.com/api/beta/myorganization/siteCollections/<site_coll_id>/sites/<site_id>/notes/pages?top=10 and got the the same result. So any route to it gives 401.

Comment: In addition to the standard HTTP response codes, the OneNote API returns headers to the calling app. Included in every response is an X-CorrelationId header and a Date header, if you cna provide me these header values for a sample 401 call, I can look into more details.

Comment: X-CorrelationId: 19302a09-78bf-4d79-8813-2de54e12c9b2
Date: Wed, 21 Oct 2015 13:25:05 GMT

Comment: When populating the Authentication header in the API requests, are you prepending the Bearer prefix to the OAuth token? Btw https://github.com/OneNoteDev/OneNoteAPISampleWinUniversal has code sample on O365 auth do it might be a good resource too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Sharad from OneNote Team, Microsoft.

We have a sample (native) app published in the GitHub

> github.com/OneNoteDev/OneNoteAPISampleWinUniversal

Please take a look at the file -

> OneNoteServiceSamplesWinUniversal.Shared/OneNoteApi/O365Auth.cs

There is resource Uri and redirect Uri. Redirect Uri is your app controlled, but resource Uri is always the same.

Code (native app):

```
private const string AuthContextUrl = "https://login.windows.net/Common"; 
private const string ResourceUri = "https://onenote.com"; 
// TODO: Replace the below RedirectUri with your app's RedirectUri. 
private const string RedirectUri = "https://localhost"; 

_authenticationResult = 
await AuthContext.AcquireTokenAsync(GetResourceHost(ResourceUri), ClientId, new Uri(RedirectUri), PromptBehavior.Always);
```

Native app - take a look at this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/onenotedev/archive/2015/04/30/support-for-work-and-school-notebooks-on-office-365-in-preview.aspx).
Web app - take a look at this [blog](https://mysharepointlearnings.wordpress.com/2015/08/03/o365-onenote-api-in-web-application/)
I hope this helps resolve your issue. Feel free to get back with fiddler trace (request/response).

Comment: I have gone through the above samples. In my case I have a console app running as a job trying to read from Onenote docs inside a SiteCollection in our Office 365 tenant. Not sure then which ClientId to use and there would not been any redirectUI in this case. The above sample seems to be more geared towards personal onedrive which I have it already working.

Comment: The sample app code I pointed you to deals with OneDrive for business. the sample app handles both OneDrive and OneDrive for business. The two blogs that I pointed you to earlier are O365 (OneDrive for business) specific and does not talk of OneDrive personal. Console app qualifies as native app. You will need to register as native app in azure AD. When you do that, you need to specify redirectUrl. I keep it as a dummy value (for native apps) e.g. http://localhost. Also when you register, you get a client Id, it is this client Id that you need to use.

Comment: Thanks. It's now working fine. I also modified to store a refreshtoken to access accesstoken so that I do not need to supply the credentials when this console application is running as a batch job.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the Authentication header in your API requests is missing the 'Bearer' prefix before the OAuth token. That's why you get a 401-Unauthorized response.
 Our [Github repo](http://github.com/OneNoteDev/OneNoteAPISampleWinUniversal) has code samples on O365 auth, it might be a good reference resource.

Comment: I followed this https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon repo. I can see the bearer toekn in request auth header going out ,
"Authorization {Bearer <access_token>} System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue"

Comment: ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireToken(todoListResourceId, clientCredential);
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
var url = GetOneNoteURI();
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);

Comment: Is your todoListResourceId set to 'https://onenote.com' ?
[source](https://github.com/OneNoteDev/OneNoteAPISampleWinUniversal/blob/master/OneNoteServiceSamplesWinUniversal.Shared/OneNoteApi/O365Auth.cs)

Comment: No it's using the APPD ID URI of the app that I have registered which has access to OneNote application and Office 365 Sharepoint Online. Shouldn't the token issued for my registered app also able to access OneNote and Office 365 Sharepoint Online since it has delegated permissions?

Comment: I'll have to consult with the area expert but I believe the Beta API currently doesnt support this. Do you mind trying it with onenote.com uri to verify Auth works?

Comment: The application named http://www.onenote.com was not found in the tenant named <tenant>.onmicrosoft.com.  This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant.  You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.\r\nTrace ID: 8cad8859-8e64-4be0-96b6-aba165f8336f\r\nCorrelation ID: 0e4781a7-3e30-4e9f-a8ba-263d2aea17e1\r\nTimestamp: 2015-10-22 17:42:51Z"

Comment: I expected the above result as the clientID passed to is tied to the tenant and there is no registered app called "onenote.com" for my tenant. The authority for authenticationContext is also https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}, so this is a valid error

Comment: We already have it working with personal one drive. Now we want it to work against OneDrive for Business and Office 365 Sharepoint Online Site Onenote docs. Do you have a working example as suggested in this blog,  "http://blogs.msdn.com/b/onenotedev/archive/2015/06/11/and-sharepoint-makes-three.aspx".